# Does the Vimeo API support upload on behalf of a specific user?

Tags: upload, oauth-2.0, vimeo-api

I see that it supports upload, using OAuth2, but that will only let the user upload to their own account, right?  I'm looking for something more along the lines of the 2 legged OAuth, where I want specific people to be able to upload to my account.  Is this possible with Vimeo?

Comment: As per vimeo documentation you need to have vimeo PRO account to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, any user can upload video in your vimeo account by using public access token :

**Steps To Get public access token**

1. Login to vimeo account and goto https://developer.vimeo.com/apps
2. Create a new app and generate public access token.
3. Use [Websemantics Vimeo Upload JS Plugin](https://github.com/websemantics/vimeo-upload) For upload video.

Thats it,

Hope this works for you,